# setting cookie through foreach loop inside while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, setcookie

I am getting an error while trying to set these cookies through a `foreach loop` inside a `while loop`. The error I am getting is ....  `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in`
php script:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $path = "/";
            $expire =  time() + 2592000;
            $expire =  date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$expire);
            $c = array(
            md5('id')=>$row['id'],
            md5('name')=>$row['u'],
            md5('sex')=>$row['s'],
            md5('country')=>$row['co'],
            md5('state')=>$row['st'],
            md5('city')=>$row['ci'],
            md5('timezone')=>$row['ti']
            );
            foreach($c as $name=>$value){
                setcookie($name,$value,$expire,$path);
            }
            echo "Logging you in! <img src=\"source/image/50gl.gif\"><br>"; 
        }
```

Comment: In which line are you getting the error?

Comment: i solved it, thanks man it was coming from me formatting the time-stamp, i just always assumed that you were allowed to put any date in the time-stamp (formatted or not)... but apparently you cant ! :)

Comment: Why do you md5 encrypt the cookie data names?

Comment: just minor security attempts md5 the names so a asshole user would stop editing the cookie name with those hacker browser like maxithon..... were they aloow a user to minupulate the cookie data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$expire` is expected to be an int. You have a string. This line is unnecessary, and the cause of the problem:

```
$expire =  date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$expire);
```

https://www.php.net/setcookie

> You may notice the expire parameter takes on a Unix timestamp, as opposed to the date format Wdy, DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT, this is because PHP does this conversion internally.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd parameter "expire" of setCookie() expects an integer but you are proving date string.
This is a Unix timestamp so is in number of seconds since the epoch.
 So, comment 
//$expire =  date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$expire);

It wil then work fine.